# Sufficient and necessary condition for BIBO stability

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control

I am looking for a reference for the proof of the next claim:

"BIBO—bounded input bounded output—stability.
We claim that a necessary and sufficient condition for a system described
by a linear, constant coefficient, time invariant, integro-differential equation
to be stable is that all of the poles of P(s)/Q(s)—all of the zeros of
Q(s)—must lie in the left half-plane"

I want a reference for the proof that it's sufficient.

Thanks, Alan. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See for instance [pp.172-173](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=WyWBPV6Cu9QC&pg=PA172) from Panos J. Antsaklis, and Anthony N. Michel. *A Linear Systems Primer*. Springer, 2007.